# whats is limit for WhatsApi sending whats app messages

Tags: c#, winforms, whatsapp

I created a Win form application using c#.
Which is send bulk whats app messages to entered / selected excel file mobile numbers.
During the making this software, Whatsapp blocked my two numbers, reason of sending multiple users limit.
I want to know that, what is the limit of sending messages using Whats API? I mean 2000 of a day or any else?
Where do i found proper information about it?

Comment: WhatsApp doesn't have a public API. Whatever you are doing may be against their Terms of Service (especially sending bulk messages).

Comment: Arturo Torres Sánchez
there are many Bulk WhatsApp messages services available in market, which way they are use ?

Comment: They surely used reverse engineering. You can either use one of such services, or reverse engineer by yourself.

Comment: I really hope there's a limit or it's flat out blocked. Already get enough spams on email, phone and text. Don't need Whatsapp spams too! (No offense, I'm sure your reasoning for bulk sending messages is legitimate but it's too easy for spammers to abuse this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no any limitation to do that , just check out your way of sending messages,
go throw bellow steps

- Login
- Sync contacts
- Send Presence Suscription
- Send Typing
- Send Paused
- Send Message
- Pool Messages

This Forum may helps you https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI/issues/800